# Can we say that a diagram commutes if we don't define a category?

Tags: category-theory

Suppose we have a commutative diagram which commutes, but there is no predefined category, for example, if we don't define the identity morphisms.

Can we say so? The only reason that I can think that this cannot be done is that maybe the notion of a commutative diagram only makes sense when talking about a category. Am I right?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could give an example.

Comment: You don't need identity morphisms to talk about a diagram commuting; you just need objects, morphisms, and composition. The resulting object is called a semicategory. Examples include some cobordism categories which by default don't have identity morphisms unless you add them in explicitly.

Comment: A category without identities is also known as a ``semigroupoid'' --- just as a monoid without unit is known as a semigroup ;-)

Comment: Thanks @QiaochuYuan

Comment: @ChrisCulter The example would be a set of partial functions as objects and certain sets as morphisms, where the composition operator is defined as the intersection.